# rtorrent: Diferent save location based on filename?

Tags: script, regex, automation, rtorrent

I have a question regarding rtorrent:

Is it possible to have a different save locations for torrents depending on their filename (or filtering via RegEx or else)?

For example, all files from a watch-dir are saved to default location, but not if they include "sometext" in their name.

I know I can set different save locations for files from different watch-directories, but I only have one watch directory for all files (and I cannot change that for several reasons).

thank you very much!

greets

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of your configuration file, what you have so far?

Comment: Hey, for sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/uZN8wd8T
Its just watching in one directory and saving to one directory...which I want to change. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this, with a fitting `set_target_path` function…

https://rtorrent-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use-cases.html#versatile-move

Comment: do i edit anything besides the labels and directories?

Comment: i got this working with an old [commit](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rtorrent-community/rtorrent-docs/560581c06aa0886cb76238fdeb30653ff81edad0/docs/examples/completion-path.sh) changing `"/done"` back to my default directory `"/files"`